# Insert Word.Document in email body?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to create a procedure that is passed an email body (with text and tables) as a Word.Document and then sends it in an email. However I can't figure out how to insert the Word.Document to the email body.

This is what I'm trying now:

```
Sub CreateDraft(Destinatary As String, CC As String, Subject As String, Body As Word.Document)
    Dim OutApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim OutInspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With OutMail
        .To = Destinatary
        .CC = CC
        .Subject = Subject
        .Display
        Set OutInspector = OutMail.GetInspector
        Set WordDoc = OutInspector.WordEditor ' How do I insert the Body object to the email?
        Call .Save
        Call .Close(False)
    End With
End Sub

Sub SendButton_Click()
    Dim WordApp As New Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
    WordApp.Visible = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:E10").Copy
    WordApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    Call CreateDraft("abc@example.com", "", "Test", WordDoc)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Word object model provides the [Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837718.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Paste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840284.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) methods. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.